# Rebuke for what commandments?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mitzvah, rebuke-tochacha

A person is obligated to rebuke a person from sinning

[Rambam Deot 6.](http://www.chabad.org/910346/)7

> It is a mitzvah for a person who sees that his fellow Jew has sinned or is following an improper path [to attempt] to correct his behavior and to inform him that he is causing himself a loss by his evil deeds as [[Leviticus 19:17]](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.17) states: "You shall surely admonish your colleague."
>
> A person who rebukes a colleague - whether because of a [wrong committed] against him or because of a matter between his colleague and God - should rebuke him privately. He should speak to him patiently and gently, informing him that he is only making these statements for his colleague's own welfare, to allow him to merit the life of the world to come.
>
> If he accepts [the rebuke], it is good; if not, he should rebuke him a second and third time. Indeed, one is obligated to rebuke a colleague who does wrong until the latter strikes him and tells him: "I will not listen."
>
> Whoever has the possibility of rebuking [sinners] and fails to do so is considered responsible for that sin, for he had the opportunity to rebuke the [sinners].

Is this only when violating a negative commandment?

If someone is violating a positive commandment must/should/can he be rebuked (in private...)?
For what commandments should/must/can rebuke be given?

Is the commandment to say the Shma the same as to put on tzitzis in regards to this?

Sources

Comment: "If someone is violating a positive commandment " - please explain how. Do you mean by not doing it at all or by doing it the wrong way? Perhaps, provide some example(s).

Comment: @DanF I am interested in all cases

Comment: I think we could use a source or two to support your assumption, i.e. that there should be rebuke for sinning. As far as I understand, the commandment of "hoche'ach tochiach" applies to when someone has personally harmed you in some way.

Comment: @DanF see halacha 4 here http://www.chabad.org/3385302/ you are probably confusing this mitzvah with the mitzvah of do not hate your brother in your heart

Comment: @DanF Re: examples I do think saying the obligation of shma and the mitzvah of putting on tzitzis whould be different in regards to rebuke

Comment: @DanF halacha 7 here http://www.chabad.org/3302356/

Comment: I don't understand the contrast being implied by your last question (Shema and tzizit). Were you trying to contrast the two? They both seem like positive commandments to me. Are you asking if there are different "levels" of rebuke for different types of positive commandments?

Comment: There is a general concept of *kol yisra'el areivim* - Jews are responsible for each other. I can't help noticing that you've linked to Chaba"d sources, so I assume you're Chaba"d? If so, Chaba"d is certainly an org. that follows this adage, esp. with their tefillin campaign. Maybe ask someone what's behind it? I see a number of them rebuking other Jews who haven't worn tefillin that day, and they get them to wear it.

Comment: @DanF yes I think shma is more of an obligation then tzitzis which might not be a complete obligation

Comment: Hmm ... that's a somewhat "fine line", but it sounds fair within this question, I suppose. Tzitzit is required only if you wear a 4-cornered garment, whereas reciting Shema twice daily doesn't have a similar pre-condition.